# How to install program from Live-CD chroot?

Tags: software-installation, live-cd, chroot

I am using Lubuntu 13.04.

How can I install programs from a Live CD from `chroot`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Live CD consists of very Limited software that needed to install a basic Ubuntu System with required software.All the software will be available in .DEB format and you can install those software in your system if you want.

Simply copy that software somewhere in your directory and then open your terminal and `cd` to that directory.

If you want to install all those packages once then simply

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb will help you.
```

If you want to install application by application then do as

```
sudo dpkg -i <place the file name here >.deb
```

hope that helps.

Comment: so if I download the. deb file I can install in my old ubuntu through access with chroot?

Comment: No need of chroot here , you can do it with 2nd command I have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use `chroot` to install software on a current system. `chroot` is a wrapper that allows you to change the root directory so anything inside the `chroot` can not change (or even see) your system. Basically you put the software in a jail and it can not do anything outside that jail.

A popular example of a `chroot` is to create your own installation Ubuntu Live DVD. You download an Ubuntu ISO, create a pseudo filesystem with `chroot` and then mount the ISO so you can alter its contents and, when done, burn the ISO to a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chroot in that way.

You have to mount the root HD somewhere such as `/mnt`

Then you have to `mount --bind` for `/dev` `/dev/pts` and `/sys`.  In some case you may also need to mount `/usr`

Then `mount proc /mnt/proc`
you may also need to copy in `resolv.conf` to get net

then chroot in